# Vee validate 4 select's selected prop doesnt work

Tags: vue.js, select, vee-validate

I'm having a problem with vee-validate package.
My problem is the package cannot handle the selected attribute.

When the condition is true in the "selected" prop, the browser doesn't select it. I'm trying like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <Field name="brand_id"
           as="select"
           class="form-control"
           id="brandSelect"
    >
        <option value="">Válassz egyet</option>

        <option v-for="brand in brands"
                :value="brand.id"
                :selected="product.brand && product.brand.id == brand.id"
        >
            {{ brand.title }}
        </option>
    </Field>
    <ErrorMessage name="brand_id" />
</div>
```

package.json:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "vite": "^3.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vee-validate": "^4.6.9",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
}
```

}

Anybody had/has this issue too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some workaround I have a solution to set the brand_id attributes correctly in the form with setFieldValue function of the correct `<Form>` ref:

```
let self = this;
Object.values(this.products).forEach(function (product) {
    if (! product.brand) {
        return;
    }

    let productFormRef = 'productForm' + product.id;

    self.$refs[productFormRef][0].setFieldValue('brand_id', product.brand.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to move the whole select inside the `Field`:

```
<Field as="div" 
       v-slot="{ field }" 
       v-model="product.brand.id" 
       name="brand_id" 
       class="form-group"
>
    <select v-bind="field"
           name="brand_id"
           class="form-control"
           id="brandSelect"
    >
        <option value="">Válassz egyet</option>
        <option v-for="brand in brands"
                :value="brand.id"
        >
            {{ brand.title }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <!-- I can't remember if/how ErrorMessage works inside the slot -->
</Field>
```